# Creating array of objects of multiple types efficienly in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, oop

I want to create an array/arraylist/list/map (not sure which one to use) of multiple objects, that would be instances of multiple classes. How perform this task without writing a separate for loop for each object type?
Something like a deck of cards but there are multiple classes of cards. In my example categories 1 through 4 extend from abstract class Card. Only functionality so far for all of them is to print their name. I get that I need an arraylist of the superclass, but how do I call the subclasses in clean fashion?

Basically I have this and it looks wrong. Not sure what to use and where to start, kinda new to Java. Thanks!

```
public class Array{

    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public fillArray() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            deck.add(new Category1());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            deck.add(new Category2());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            deck.add(new Category3());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            deck.add(new Category4());
        }
        
    }
    public void printArray() {
        int k = 1;
        for (Card card : this.deck) {
            System.out.println(k+". "+card.getName());
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using arrays/ array list but never got them to properly call the class to construct an object.

Comment: Any time you see multiple variable names that end in incrementing numbers, think of creating another list or array, and then use them in a nested for loop.

Comment: Also note that details matter and you may consider making your question and your code less abstract and more concrete.

Comment: my problem is, even if I construct a list of these methods, how do I properly call the classes to construct an object? how do I save them into a list properly, so I can create x amounts of objects?

Comment: Perhaps this is more of a design issue. Why do you need four subclasses of `Card`?

Comment: each card class has different functionality

Comment: You're doing it. There's nothing wrong with this code. What is your specific question, other than 'it feels wrong', which... isn't an actionable question? Given that you have 4 separate classes with unique functionality, you can't skirt around the notion of having 4 separate initialization procedures. You can go ham with some factories or a `Supplier<Card>` or whatnot to abstract away the construction itself but this wouldn't be a worthwhile idea unless your app has more specific needs than this rather general overview indicates.

Comment: I wanted to put them into an array to not have 30 lines of code doing just for loop for each class. If this is the way to go, so be it.

Answer (score 2):

As rzwiterloot says, your current code is clear and quite concise.

One improvement to make your code clearer is to *not* call your class `Array`, which is also used by the JDK.

If you want to make your code more concise, but less clear, you could create a method which adds cards:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Test {
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public void fillArray() {
        addCards(10, () -> new Category1());
        addCards(20, () -> new Category2());
        addCards(5, () -> new Category3());
        addCards(8, Category4::new); // this is exactly the same as () -> new Category4()
    }
    
    private void addCards(int howMany, Supplier<Card> cardFactory) {
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            deck.add(cardFactory.get());
        }
    }
    
    public void printArray() {
        int k = 1;
        for (Card card : this.deck) {
            System.out.println(k+". "+card.getName());
            k++;
        }
    }
}

class Card { public String getName() { return "";}}
class Category1 extends Card {}
class Category2 extends Card {}
class Category3 extends Card {}
class Category4 extends Card {}
```

But to reiterate: your current code is fine. If the code above is harder for you to understand, don't use it.

Creating a method like this is good if it removes duplicated code, but you don't have significant duplicated code.